# showing wijmo menu on jquery dialog box

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-dialog, wijmo

I'm new to wijmo. I have opened one dialog box in my project. And **I want to open some wijmo menus on my dialog box**. For this i done following things-

**jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#wijmenu1").wijmenu({
            trigger: "#downArrow_imgEmailIdTest",
            triggerEvent: "mouseenter",
            orientation: "vertical"
        })
    });
```

**html code-**

```
<span id="downArrow_imgEmailIdTest">Menu</span>
             <ul id="wijmenu1"> 
                <li><a href="#">Breaking News</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li> 
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li> 
            </ul>
```

It is not opening my wijmo menu as well as I checked generated html on browser and it is not adding any classes realted to wijmo menu to my menu.

How to do this ? Am I doing right steps?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works well with the latest version 20132.9. Here is the code which I used:

```
        $('#dialog').wijdialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            captionButtons: {
                refresh: { visible: false }
            }
        });
        $("#wijmenu1").wijmenu({
            trigger: "#spanID",
            triggerEvent: "mouseenter",
            orientation: "vertical"
        })
```

HTML Code

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <span id="spanID">test</span>
            <ul id="wijmenu1">
                <li><a href="#">Breaking News</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Entertainment</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finance</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Politics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Sports</a></li>
           </ul>
</div>
```

Let me know if it does not help.